# Customize event label for Brightcove videos on GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, brightcove

I'm quite new to GTM and have been trying to figure out how to get the video title to populate as the event label? I was trying on the script provided [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/google-tag-manager-recipes/html5-video/) but I cannot make the event label work; I don't know how to call the video_title in Brightcove.

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't using the Brightcove API at all, just attaching event listeners to the video element. It doesn't have any concept of video metadata, like name. You could try replacing this part.

```js
'eventLabel': decodeURIComponent(e.target.currentSrc.split('/')[e.target.currentSrc.split('/').length - 1])
```

with this

```js
'eventLabel': decodeURIComponent(e.target.parentElement.player.mediainfo.name)
```

Comment: Also, see Brightcove's GTM integration https://player.support.brightcove.com/plugins/google-tag-manager-plugin-brightcove-player.html